# Factory reset a rooted 4.4.4 and lost the keyboard

Tags: factory-reset, swiftkey

I factory-reset my Android 4.4.4 phone and lost my Swiftkey keyboard, which upon installing originally, I erased the standard Samsung keypad.

Now only only voice is available, and I cannot get into my Samsung or Google accounts to get things going again, because saying a password is impossible. All I want is access to a keyboard. What can I do?

Comment: appears my basic os is not working either

Answer (score 2):

A factory reset removes user apps and data, leaving the system partition alone.  It sounds like you removed the system keyboard and had a user keyboard erased.  You could sideload a keyboard with `adb` or something, but based on your comment that the OS is not working in general it would probably be better to flash a ROM (presumably whatever ROM you're already using, whether the original software or a custom build).

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but i got the OS going, but how do I do the adb keyboard? thanks

Comment: @DiegoDuranMontemayor Download an APK file for a keyboard, such as [this one](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-keyboard/google-keyboard-4-1-23154-2501950-android-apk-download/), connect your phone to your computer, and run `adb install name-of-download.apk`.  To find out more about adb or to obtain it: http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info

Comment: you are a lifesaver

Comment: @DiegoDuranMontemayor, you can also sideload using GUI (if you're not comfortable with command-line). Download or copy the APK into phone and tap on the APK file using a file manager. You would be asked to enable Unknown sources setting. Past that, tap the APK again and proceed with installation.